# How to handle Laravel Validator Exist default function when it fails

Tags: php, laravel, validation

## Background

So I have a validator:

1. To determine whether an email format is correct or not
2. Does the **email already exist** in the database
3. Along with some other column validation (*just ignore this*)
   Like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:MyTable,email',
    'mobile' => ['required', 'regex:/^(62)8[1-9][0-9]{6,9}$/'], // Valid: 6281234567890
    'birthdate' => 'required|date',
    'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Password::min(8)->mixedCase()->numbers()],
    'allow_received_information' => 'integer',
]);
```

Error messages will be displayed one by one if there is an error in the input form with this code:

```
if ($validator->stopOnFirstFailure()->fails()) {
    return ResponseFormatter::error(null, implode(",", $validator->messages()->all()));
}
```

### Question

So my question is, how to catch the event **if an email already exists in the database or not** among other validations?
Maybe it's as simple as this:

```
if ('email' == alreadyExistFunc()) {
    # if already exist in db
} else {
    # if not
}
```

### Trial 1

I found some functionality from [Laravel's After Validation Hook](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#after-validation-hook), but I don't know if this is the exact function I need, and I don't know how to use it either..

```
$validator = Validator::make();
 
$validator->after(function ($validator) {
    if ($this->somethingElseIsInvalid()) {
        $validator->errors()->add(
            'field', 'Something is wrong with this field!'
        );
    }
});
 
if ($validator->fails()) {
    //
}
```

### Trial 2

I could just remove the email validation `'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:MyTable,email'` from the rule code line, and do it manually like this:

```
$isExist = MyTable::where('email', $request->email)->first();

if ($isExist != null) {
    # code...
} else {
    # code...
}
```

But is it best practice?
I think there is a way automatically..

Please for suggestions or answers, thank you

Comment: Don’t bother stopping on the first validation error and all your problems with how to catch the other scenarios will be sorted. I would also be very frustrated if I was only shown a single error at a time. Just show and/all errors at the same time, a much better user experience.

Comment: Hmm, I think it's a good choice, because it's for mobile API usage, so I think User will find it easier to fix one error at a time, not with a pile of existing errors.. Is that right?

Comment: Not really. Consider the performance and data usage of having multiple network requests. If you’re doing real time validating then fine, but not if you fill out 7 fields, press submit and only get one validation error at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to the answer mentioned by [Pouria Jahedi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74441946/9039350), and through [this reference](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#retrieving-the-first-error-message-for-a-field), we can do logical conditioning like this:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
     $errors = $validator->errors();
     if ($errors->first('email')) {
         return $errors->first('email');
     } else {
         return ResponseFormatter::error(null, implode(", ", $errors->all()));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => 'required|unique:MyTable,email|string|email|max:255',
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
]);
```

here's a list of methods available for your $error message bag in Laravel API: https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Contracts/Support/MessageBag.html

You can get a list of all error keys with:

```
$error->keys()
```

Or errors list with:

```
$errors->all()
```

Or a specific error by its key with:

```
$error->get('email')
```

Comment: Thanks to mention that, this made me realize how to use it like the one in [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#retrieving-the-first-error-message-for-a-field). And if possible the error variable in your answer should be added `s` as [documented](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#error-message-indexes-and-positions:~:text=When%20using%20this,to%20the%20user)